# Comparing flags with flags - check for matches

Tags: c#, enums, comparison, enum-flags

Say I have an enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum Alpha
{
    NULL = 0,
    A0 = 1,
    A1 = 2,
    A2 = 4,
    A3 = 8
}
```

And I have the following:

```
Alpha selected = A0 | A1 | A2

Alpha compare = A1 | A3
```

I want to check if any of the `selected` flags are also in the `compare` flags.

The only way I can think to do this so far is (pseudocode)

```
foreach(Alpha flag in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Alpha)))
{
    if (selected.HasFlag(flag) && compare.HasFlag(flag))
    {
        return true
    }
}
return false
```

Is there a more logic-al way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is treated as bit field, you can use it in the same fashion.

[FlagsAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx)

> Indicates that an enumeration can be treated as a bit field; that is,
>   a set of flags

```
bool result = (selected & compare) > 0; // First solution
bool result2 = (selected & compare).Any(); // Second solution
```

Comment: This answer is producing incorrect results. It checks whether ALL the flags in "selected" exists in "compare". Did you test your answer with selected = A1|A2|A3 and compare = A1|A3 ? It evaluates to false.

Comment: Fix. Sorry my bad, thought he wanted to check if all of the flags exists and not only if one flag exists. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: No problem. The very first thing we need to make sure is to get the requirements right :)

Comment: Where does `.Any()` come in? I don't get the option in intellisense

Comment: @simon it is an extension method. Just add using System.Linq;

Comment: I am using Linq, it's still not there (VS2015)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is probably:

```
(selected & compare) > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use an `AND` operator, any flag which is common between the two operands will be present in the result.

Then you just have to compare and see if the result is greater than Zero:

```
bool anySelected = (selected & compare) > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think first you should remove the `NULL` from the Alpha, then just return `(selected & compare) != 0`, `anyEnum.HasFlag(Alpha.NULL)` will always be ture.